# MySQL: What is the best way to do these multiple batch INSERTs?

Tags: mysql, batch-processing

I have a MySQL database (InnoDB, if that matters) and I want to add a lot of rows. I want to do this on a production database so there can be no downtime. Each time (about once a day) I want to add about 1M rows to the database, in batches of 10k (from some tests I ran this seemed to be the optimal batch size to minimize time). While I'm doing these inserts the table needs to be readable. What is the "correct" way to do this? For starters you can assume there are no indexes.

Option A: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

`START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO my_table (etc etc batch insert);
INSERT INTO my_table (etc etc batch insert);
INSERT INTO my_table (etc etc batch insert);
INSERT INTO my_table (etc etc batch insert);
(more)
COMMIT;
SET autocommit = 0;`

Options B

`copy my_table into my_table_temp
INSERT INTO my_table_temp (etc etc batch insert);
INSERT INTO my_table_temp (etc etc batch insert);
INSERT INTO my_table_temp (etc etc batch insert);
INSERT INTO my_table_temp (etc etc batch insert);
(more)
RENAME my_table TO my_table_old;
RENAME my_table_temp TO my_table;`

I've used the second method before and it works. There's only a tiny amount of time where something might be wrong which is the time it takes to rename the tables.

But my confusion is: if this were the best solution, then what's the point of `START TRANSACTION`/`COMMIT`? Surely that was invented to take care of the thing I'm describing, no?

Bonus question: What if we have indexes? My case is easily adaptable, just turn off the indexes in the temp table and turn them back on after the inserts were finished and before the rename. What about option A? Seems hard to reconciliate with doing inserts with indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then what's the point of START TRANSACTION/COMMIT? Surely that was invented to take care of the thing I'm describing, no?

Yes, exactly. In InnoDB, thanks to its [MVCC architecture](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multi-versioning.html), writers never block readers. You don't have to worry about bulk inserts blocking readers.

The exception is if you're doing *locking reads* with `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT...LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. Those might conflict with INSERTs, depending on the data you're selecting, and whether it requires gap locks where the new data is being inserted.

Likewise `LOAD DATA INFILE` does not block non-locking readers of the table.

You might like to see the results I got for bulk loading data in my presentation, [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

> There's only a tiny amount of time where something might be wrong which is the time it takes to rename the tables.

It's not necessary to do the table-swapping for bulk INSERT, but for what it's worth, if you ever do need to do that, you can do multiple table renames in one statement. The operation is atomic, so there's no chance any concurrent transaction can sneak in between.

```
RENAME my_table TO my_table_old, my_table_temp TO my_table;
```

---

Re your comments:

> what if I have indexes?

Let the indexes be updated incrementally as you do the INSERT or LOAD DATA INFILE. InnoDB will do this while other concurrent reads are using the index.

There is overhead to updating an index during INSERTs, but it's usually preferable to let the INSERT take a little longer instead of disabling the index.

If you disable the index, then *all* concurrent clients cannot use it. Other queries will slow down. Also, when you re-enable the index, this will lock the table and block other queries while it rebuilds the index. Avoid this.

> why do I need to wrap the thing in "START TRANSACTION/COMMIT"?

The primary purpose of a transaction is to group changes that should be committed as one change, so that no other concurrent query sees the change in a partially-complete state. Ideally, we'd do all your INSERTs for your bulk-load in one transaction.

The secondary purpose of the transaction is to reduce overhead. If you rely on autocommit instead of explicitly starting and committing, **you're still using transactions**—but autocommit implicitly starts and commits one transaction for every INSERT statement. The overhead of starting and committing is small, but it adds up if you do it 1 million times.

There's also a practical, physical reason to reduce the number of individual transactions. InnoDB by default does a filesystem sync after each commit, to ensure data is safely stored on disk. This is important to prevent data loss if you have a crash. But a filesystem sync isn't free. You can only do a finite number of syncs per second (this varies based on what type of disk you use). So if you are trying to do 1 million syncs for individual transactions, but your disk can only physically do 100 syncs per second (this typical for a single hard disk of the non-SSD type), then your bulk load will take a minimum of 10,000 seconds. This is a good reason to group your bulk INSERT into batches.

So for both logical reasons of atomic updates, and physical reasons of being kind to your hardware, use transactions when you have some bulk work to do.

However, I don't want to scare you into using transactions to group things inappropriately. Do commit your work promptly after you do some other type of UPDATE. Leaving a transaction hanging open for an unbounded amount of time is not a good idea either. MySQL can handle the rate of commits of ordinary day-to-day work. I am suggesting batching work when you need to do a bunch of bulk changes in rapid succession.

Comment: Very good, thank you. So essentally your answer is "just to the bulk inserts into the table directly and InnoDB will take care of the rest". Ok, so what if I have indexes? From what I understand, turning off indexes during big inserts significantly speeds up the process because it avoids having to have the indexes re-calculated after each insert. Does your answer still make sense for the case with indexes?

Comment: No, I'm still confused. If indeed the asnwer (without indexes) is "just bulk insert and InnoDB will take care of it", why do I need to wrap the thing in "START TRANSACTION/COMMIT"?

Comment: Thank you very much. You've answered everything. I also understood that I don't really need transactions, because I don't mind if users get reads in between each of the bulk inserts. Just one last clarification. When you say "but autocommit implicitly starts and commits one transaction for every INSERT statement. The overhead of starting and committing is small, but it adds up if you do it 1 million times." in this case since I have of order 1M lines and batches of 10k rows, that's only 100 inserts. 100 syncs doesn't seem so bad. Thank you for the answer and for the links!

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best way is [LOAD DATA IN FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Does LOAD DATA IN FILE address the points I made? What is happening as that command is running? Can you read?